# Unable to run celery task that depends on Django code

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I seemingly have a bit of a catch 22 scenario when trying to run a celery task that depends on django code.

**Celery code**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from celery import shared_task
from celery import task
from letters.send_write_letter_reminders import send_write_letter_reminders

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_name.settings')

app = Celery('app_name')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/London'
# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True, name='send_letter_reminders')
def send_letter_reminders(slug=None):
    send_write_letter_reminders(slug=slug)
```

The problem I've run into is that with this line

```
from letters.send_write_letter_reminders import send_write_letter_reminders
```

With it I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

And the app server won't run, but without it I get:

```
NameError: name 'send_write_letter_reminders' is not defined
```

Obviously I'm missing something fundamental about how to run Celery and Django together, but I can't see it. Can anyone enlighten me as to what I've done wrong?

**Update**
I've come up with a hacky workaround for this, which involves moving the import to within the celery task. I realise this isn't best practice. Perhaps it might help explain what's going on though.

```
@app.task(bind=True, name='send_letter_reminders')
def send_letter_reminders(slug=None):
    from letters.send_write_letter_reminders import send_write_letter_reminders
    send_write_letter_reminders.send_write_letter_reminders(slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you can't do any django imports or import anything that relies on django until after you have executed the `os.environ.setdefault` line.  The reason that you don't have to worry about this with anything run from `manage.py` is because the `os.environ.setdefault` is the first line of the manage.py.  Essentially, just move the `django.conf` and `letter` import to below the `os.environ.setdefault` and things should work better.  Depending on which version of django you are on, you may also need to explicitly call `django.setup()` after setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to complete django setup.